How to properly perform one-to-many relationship query in sequelize-typescript?
I've a question to ask and probably would like to apply it on my personal project. I have Photo and Album as my tables and subsequently on my code as my data models:
Album.ts
 import { Column, CreatedAt, DataType, HasMany, Model, PrimaryKey, Table, UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
 import { Photo } from "./photo";

 @Table({
  timestamps: true,
  deletedAt: "albumDeletedAt",
  paranoid: true,
  createdAt: true,
  updatedAt: true
})
 export class Album extends Model {
 @PrimaryKey
 @Column({
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
 })
 declare id: number;

 @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 })
 declare name: string;

 @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: true
 })
 declare description?: string;

 @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING,
    allowNull: false
 })
 declare thumbnailURL: string;

 @HasMany(() => Photo)
 declare photos: Photo[];

 @CreatedAt
 declare createdAt: Date;

 @UpdatedAt
 declare updatedAt: Date;
}

Photo.ts
  import { BelongsTo, Column, CreatedAt, DataType, ForeignKey, Model, PrimaryKey, Table, UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
  import { Album } from "./album";

  @Table({
   timestamps: true,
   deletedAt: "photoDeletedAt",
   paranoid: true,
   createdAt: true,
   updatedAt: true
  })
  export class Photo extends Model {
   @PrimaryKey
   @Column({
     type: DataType.INTEGER,
     primaryKey: true,
     autoIncrement: true
   })
   declare id: number;

   @Column({
     type: DataType.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   })
   declare name: string;

   @Column({
     type: DataType.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   })
   declare photoURL: string;

   @ForeignKey(() => Album)
   @Column({
      type: DataType.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
   })
   declare albumId: number;

   @BelongsTo(() => Album)
   declare album: Album;

   @CreatedAt
   declare createdAt: Date;

   @UpdatedAt
   declare updatedAt: Date;
  }

The relationship between this two models are one-to-many where one Album can have 1 or more Photo.ts. Here's the query I coded using sequelize-typescript:
public async getAlbumById(id: number): Promise<Album | null> {
    try {
        const searchedResult = await this.albumRepository.findByPk(id, {
            include: {
                model: this.photoRepository,
                where: {
                    albumId: id
                }
            },
            raw: true,
            nest: true
        });

        return searchedResult;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error finding the album via ID for the ID of ${id} due to`, error);
        return null;
    }
}

I know that in one of the Album id, it has more than 3 Photo but the library only returns one Photo which is incorrect:
{
"name": "Sample Card Photos Album (Test)",
"description": "Pictures for testing placeholder",
"thumbnailURL": "",
"photos": [
    {
        "name": "beautiful-village-snow-covered-mountain.jpg",
        "photoURL": "http://localhost:8080/uploads/pictures/Sample_Card_Photos_Album_(Test)/beautiful-village-snow-covered-mountain.jpg"
    }
"albumDeletedAt": null
}

Here are the screenshots in database:


I'm unsure if this is a bug in the sequelize-typescript library or there's some problem to the code. If anyone has any experience and would like to shed some light, please do so. Thanks!

Run the same query without using raw: true, & nest: true and let me now.

Without raw: true & nest: true causes the following error:
Error finding the album via ID for the ID of 8 due to TypeError: result.get is not a function
Mind you that I'm using repositoryMode: true

SHOW CREATE TABLE for the two tables.

I'm unsure what you're asking, do you mean by running the command SHOW CREATE TABLE
